# Do I need to integrate a PDF of a counting process in order to find the probability the count is > k? Specifically interested in Poisson processes

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a homogenous Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. I want to find the probability $N(4,8)>5$. Note, $N(,)$ denotes a counting process, which here is specifically Poisson.

The probability $N(4,8) = 5$ is computed as follows
$$\Bbb P (N(4,8) = 5) = \frac{[\lambda (8-4)]^5}{5!}e^{-\lambda (8-4)} $$

I naturally thought therefore to compute $\Bbb P (N(4,8)>5)$ that I might simply integrate from $[5,\infty)$, but this turned out to be really ugly and I am pretty sure that train of thought is wrong.

Can someone explain why it doesn't make sense to compute  $\Bbb P (N(4,8)>5)$ by integrating the PDF? If that is the correct way to do it, can you explain how? I am particularly confused by how to handle the factorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is a discrete random variable, so you don't integrate. Second, you would be adding up getting 6 or 7 or 8, .... 
So it would be
\begin{align*}
P(N(4,8) >5) &=P[N(4,8) =6]+P[N(4,8)=7]+P[N(4,8)=8]+\dotsb\\
&= \sum_{k = 6}^\infty e^{-4\lambda }\frac{(4\lambda)^k}{k!}.
\end{align*}
Equivalently, you can calculate the complement,
$$
P(N(4,8) > 5) = 1-P(N(4,8) \leq 5) = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^5e^{-4\lambda}\frac{(4\lambda)^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: I follow the sums, but why is it discrete?

Comment: @StanShunpike What are the possbile values of the random variable $N(4,8)$?

Comment: Thought about it and realized it. Thanks.

Comment: @StanShunpike Great. Good luck.